# I am gettein an error c++ assertion failure heap corruption detected

Tags: c++, heap-corruption

> when i run this code i get an error during the destructor any ideas?
>   the data members of FloatArray are....
>   float* mData;     int mSize;

the error I get is HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after normal block (#141) at 0x004c7db8

```
#ifndef FLOAT_ARRAY_H
#define FLOAT_ARRAY_H
class FloatArray
{
public:
    // Create a FloatArray with zero elements.
    FloatArray();

    // Create a FloatArray with 'size' elements.
    FloatArray(int size);

    // Create a FloatArray from another FloatArray--
    // be sure to prevent memory leaks!
    FloatArray(const FloatArray& rhs);

    // Free dynamic memory.
    ~FloatArray();

    // Define how a FloatArray shall be assigned to
    // another FloatArray--be sure to prevent memory
    // leaks!
    FloatArray& operator=(const FloatArray& rhs);

    // Resize the FloatArray to a new size.
    void resize(int newSize);

    // Return the number of elements in the array.
    int size();

    // Overload bracket operator so client can index
    // into FloatArray objects and access the elements.
    float& operator[](int i);

private:
    float* mData; // Pointer to array of floats (dynamic memory).
    int mSize; // The number of elements in the array.
};
#endif // FLOAT_ARRAY_H


#include "FloatArray.h"

FloatArray::FloatArray()
{
    mData = new float[0];
}

FloatArray::FloatArray(int size)
{
    mData = new float[size];
    mSize = size;
}

FloatArray::FloatArray(const FloatArray& rhs)
{
    mData = new float[rhs.mSize];
    mSize = rhs.mSize;

    for (int i = 0; i < rhs.mSize; i++)
    {
        mData[i] = rhs.mData[i];
    }

}

FloatArray::~FloatArray()
{
    delete[] mData;
    mData = 0;
}

FloatArray& FloatArray::operator=(const FloatArray& rhs)
{
    if (this == &rhs)
        return *this;

    delete[] mData;

    mData = new float[rhs.mSize];
    mSize = rhs.mSize;

    for (int i = 0; i < rhs.mSize; i++)
    {
        mData[i] = rhs.mData[i];
    }

    return *this;
}

void FloatArray::resize(int newSize)
{
    mSize = newSize;
}

int FloatArray::size()
{
    return mSize;
}

float& FloatArray::operator[](int i)
{
    return mData[i];
}

#include "FloatArray.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void PrintFloatArray(FloatArray& fa)
{
    cout << "{ ";
    for (int i = 0; i < fa.size(); ++i)
        cout << fa[i] << " ";
    cout << "}" << endl << endl;
}
int main()
{
    FloatArray A;
    A.resize(4);
    A[0] = 1.0f;
    A[1] = 2.0f;
    A[2] = 3.0f;
    A[3] = 4.0f;
    cout << "Printing A: ";
    PrintFloatArray(A);
    FloatArray B(A);
    cout << "Printing B: ";
    PrintFloatArray(B);
    FloatArray C = B = A;
    cout << "Printing C: ";
    PrintFloatArray(C);
    A = A = A = A;
    cout << "Printing A: ";
    PrintFloatArray(A);
}
```

Comment: A side note:  Your `operator=` has issues.  You destroyed your data by calling `delete[]` before you are sure that `new[]` will be successful.

Comment: I'm still really new to this but if you make a new array before deleting the old one won't that cause a mem leak?

Comment: `FloatArray& FloatArray::operator=(FloatArray rhs) { std::swap(rhs.mSize, mSize); std::swap(rhs.mData, mData); return *this;}`  That version of the assignment operator removes those issues, plus no test for self-assignment need be done.

Comment: The only way to write the assignment operator using your method is to allocate to a temporary variable first, move the data to the temp location, delete the old data, and then assign the temp pointer to the actual member.  But I posted a safe and easier way (look up "copy/swap").

Comment: Thank you that fixed the error and you answered the question in like 54 secs. You are awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't initialize `mSize` to 0 in default constructor `FloatArray::FloatArray()`.

Also, in `resize()`, you only change `mSize` but did not allocate enough memory for new size.